# What does Jesus call God?

Tags: life-of-jesus

Is it accurate that it was only on the cross that Jesus referred to God as "God"?

> My God why has thou forsaken me?
>
> Matthew 27:46

Comment: Father and my god

Answer (score 5):

No, prior to the cross, Jesus spoke of God as ‘God’. In Mark 12:29-30 he quoted the Shema from Deuteronomy 6:4-5 which says,

> “Hear, O Israel. The Lord our God, the Lord is one. Love the Lord your
>   God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your
>   strength.”

A few verses further on in Mark’s gospel, Jesus commends one of the teachers of the Law by saying, “You are not far from the kingdom of God.” (vs 34)

Then, after his resurrection, Jesus said to Mary, “I am returning to my Father and your Father, to my God and your God.” (John 20:17)

You quote from Mark 15:34, (or Matthew 27:46) which relates an event sandwiched between those two other occurrences of Jesus speaking of God as ‘God’. On that occasion, Jesus spoke in Aramaic the words, ‘Eloi, Eloi, lama sabachthani?’ which means, ‘My God, my God. Why have you forsaken me?’ This was a quotation from Psalm 22:1 and verses 6-8 also happened while Jesus was on the cross when he was scorned, despised and insulted with the challenge, ‘He trusts in the Lord, let the Lord rescue him’.” Verses 16 and 18 also happened: they pierced his hands and his feet, and cast lots for his clothes. Prior to that cry of dereliction, Jesus had called God his Father while on the cross (as in Luke 23:34, “Father, forgive them, for they do not know what they are doing.”) But before Jesus breathed his last, he was able to call God his Father, once more. “Jesus called out with a loud voice, ‘Father, into your hands I commit my spirit’.” (vs 46)

Jesus mainly addressed God as his Father, and spoke of himself as God the Father’s Son.

Answer (score 1):

Jesus is quoting the beginning of Psalm 22.  This is part of Christ fulfilling the Law and Prophets. The Psalm is a Psalm of Victory and Deliverance.

Jewish witness would recognize what Christ was referring to when he quoted the Psalm, it would not make them think God had abandoned them at all, but would, like hearing a familiar song on the radio, bring to mind the rest of the Psalm which point to the salvation of the Lord.

"The afflicted shall eat and be satisfied; those who seek him shall praise the Lord!"

There is always more to Scripture than what it on the page.

Comment: This is good background about the Psalm, but doesn't address whether Jesus used the word "God" elsewhere.